# How to compare associative array with result_array in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Need to bind Page drop-down conditionally on base of 'Content' table. Page titles are stored in an associative array and 'Content' table have page code stored in it. Here is the code

**Function which return page titles**

```
    public function getPageTitles(){    
     $pageTitles = array("Home"=> "Home", 
              "AboutUs"=> "About Us", //AboutUs will save in database as pageCode
              "Features"=> "Features",
              "ContactUs"=> "Contact Us");

     return $pageTitles;
  }
```

**Function which checks if page have content or not:**

```
public function getPageTitlesWithNoContent()
{
    $pageTitles = $this->getPageTitles();

    $this->db->distinct('pageCode');
        $this->db->select('pageCode');
        $this->db->from('content');
    $this->db->where('status', 1);      
    $data = $this->db->get();

    $queryResult = $data ? $data->result_array() : 0 ;

    $emptyPageTitle = array();

    foreach($pageTitles as $x => $x_value)
    {
        $hasContent = in_array($x, $queryResult);

        if (!$hasContent){ 
         $emptyPageTitle[$x] = $x_value;
        }
    }

    return $emptyPageTitle;
}
```

This function is returning all page titles.. new to php no idea what is wrong

Comment: What's the print result of `$queryResult`?

Comment: well how to print it? .. first time working on php code .. not even able to setup a debugger :(

Comment: `print_r($queryResult);`

Comment: when I used this .. browser is not able to open the page "This site can’t be reached
The webpage at http://localhost/pages might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."

Comment: @TamilvananN print result is "Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => Home ) [1] => Array ( [key] => ContactUs ) )" .. ok so I need to compare with value . .will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NMathur I think you almost got it. Made some changes for you in that code, Check it.

```
public function getPageTitlesWithNoContent() {

    $pageTitles = $this->getPageTitles();

    $this->db->select('pageCode');
    $this->db->from('content');
    $this->db->where('status', 1); 
    $this->db->group_by('pageCode');      
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $queryResult = array();

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) { // This loop should need to form an array based on query result
       $queryResult[$row['pageCode']] = $row['pageCode'];
    }

    $emptyPageTitle = array_diff_key($pageTitles,$queryResult); // Compares the keys from array1 against the keys from array2 and returns the difference

    return $emptyPageTitle;

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and guidance .. I learnt a lot

Answer (score 2):

Check name fields in table is same? With Uppercase first char?

Also change your code in this loop:

```
foreach($pageTitles as $x => $x_value)
{
    if (in_array($x, $queryResult)){ 
     $emptyPageTitle[$x] = $x_value;
    }
}
```

I remove ! negative in check condition

Comment: sorry .. this comment is not clear to me "Check name fields in table is same? With Uppercase first char?" ..

Comment: `$pageTitles = array("Home"=> "Home", 
              "AboutUs"=> "About Us", //AboutUs will save in database as pageCode
              "Features"=> "Features",
              "ContactUs"=> "Contact Us");` in this array your list name of fields. This names also in you table structure? They are the same? With what do you compare this array?

Comment: Provide values of array `$queryResult` which data you get from query.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => Home ) [1] => Array ( [key] => ContactUs )

Answer (score 1):

As @TamilvananN guided, I printed the queryResult and tried this workaround:

```
    foreach($pageTitles as $x => $x_value)
        {
            foreach ($queryResult as $item) 
            {
                if (!($x == $item['pageCode'])){ 
                 $emptyPageTitle[$x] = $x_value;
                }
            }
        }
```

It is working, but as you can see this has loop in a loop .. that can be very costly .. can you please share any fast way to compare the results.